# how to write streams in java

Tags: java, stream

> Q: Given a list of Persons, return the first two Students having the last name starting with “C”

My classes:

**Person class**

```
public class Person {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected int age;
}
```

**Student class**

```
public class Student extends Person {
}
```

**Method**

```
public static List<Student> findStudentsByFirstLetterFromLastName(List<Person> list) {

    return list.stream()
            .filter(person -> person instanceof Student
                    && person.getLastName() != null
                    && person.getLastName().length() > 0
                    && person.getLastName().charAt(0) == 'C')
            .map(person -> (Student) person)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? I've tried to think about the edge cases that's why there are many conditions in filter

Comment: You are missing part of the task: "return the **first two** Students".

Comment: I would sort the stream before processing it. Given it is not clear if it is already sorted in this question. Since you are using an object which doesn't implement Comparator you can use [this][1] version of the sort call for the stream. And as RoToRa pointed out you need to retrieve the first two and not all matching students.

[1][https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-]

Comment: @Nico The task doesn't call for or require for any sorting.

Comment: @RoToRa it's unclear whether sorting is required. _the first two_ -> according to which comparison method? This question is unclear.

Comment: @dfhwze The input is a `List` so it already has an order. "The first two" is very unambiguous without needing a comparison method. It would be something else if the input were a `Collection` or a `Set`.

Comment: Why was this closed. Sure it didn't fullfill the task, but it only has to be correct **to the best of the author's knowledge**, and IMHO the author did believe that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using one large boolean expression with `&&` is not wrong and most efficient way, however if the focus is on using streams, then it would make more sense to put each sub-expression into a separate `.filter()`:

```
.filter(person -> person instanceof Student)
.filter(persion -> person.getLastName() != null)
.filter(persion -> person.getLastName().length() > 0)
.filter(persion -> person.getLastName().charAt(0) == 'C')
```

To simplify it, instead of checking the length and the first character, you could use `.startsWith()`:

```
.filter(persion -> person.getLastName().startsWith("C"))
```

Alternatively to get rid of repeatingly calling `person.getLastName()` moving that check into a separate method:

```
.filter(ClassName::checkLastName) // ClassName being this classes name

private static boolean checkLastName(Person persion) {
    String lastName = person.getLastName();
    return lastName != null && lastName.startsWith("C");
}
```

Comment: First you report part of the solution is missing and then you answer the question? How can we vote to close?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Because any correction to the code would no effect on the validity of the review of the existing code. Also rules state the code has to be correct **to the best of the author's knowledge**, which I believe it was.